# Как методом вывести имя объекта класса? С++

Tags: c++, объекты

Есть объект Вася класса Студент.
Нужно создать метод void, который выводидит название объекта, т.е. строчку "Вася"

Comment: Имя переменной в коде узнать невозможно. Добавьте в класс какой-нибудь `std::string name;`.

Answer (score 0):

Если обьект глобальный, то можно  прочитать файл выполнения. Допустим его имя _ `test.cpp`. Тогда можно поиграться(но не более того) так:

```
// test.cpp :
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

struct student {/*...*/ };
student Vasia;
void foo()
{
    ifstream in("test.cpp");
    using It = std::istream_iterator<string>;
    auto p = std::find(It(in), It(), "student");
    p = std::find(++p, It(), "student");
    cout << *++p;
}
int main() {          
    foo();   
    return 0;
}
```